# Forms with associated select element

Tags: html

how do I create a web form which has two select elements, where when you select an option on the first select element the options on the next select element will be dependant on what you selected on the first select element?

For example if you have four faculties and each faculty has a number of courses associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to detect the value of the first select element by placing the script in the second select element. 
If this is the case, it would be advisable to place the first select element inside a form and and name it.

```
<script>
var select=document.forms["form-name"]["first-select-element-name"].value;
if(select=="option-one")
{
   //Do this
}
else if(select=="option-two")
{
  //Do this
}
```